Kivy imports only importing select choices
I am working on this project and 6/9 of the things that I need to import are greyed out, and all but one of them are referenced in either the py or kv file. I cannot get this to open. I just downloaded Kivy for the first time two days ago from their site, it downloaded a depreciated version instead of the current one and I cannot figure out how to update it, very frustrated that it would download an old version. Not sure if that is causing the greyed out items. But, I need them to work so the application will work.
Can someone tell me how to fix this please so I can get this working and continue with my project. This is on a fully updated Mac

Try >
pip install --update kivy
or get the latest git repo
The greyed out elements also appear from time to time. Unless I am mistaken, this means that you are not using the classes you are importing in your Python file. For example, if you use
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

and do not define BoxLayout in your Python file, it will be greyed out.
This does not mean that you cannot use the BoxLayout in your kv file.
I hope it helps and I have understood correctly where your problem is
